# javascript tabs slider doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, dom-events, magento2, alpine.js

I'm working with Magento2, but the problem is pure Javascript.

I've got this tabs carousel, each tab i click shows a different carousel.
But the only one that works fine is the first, the other ones are not moving at all.

So I tried to dispatch an event (using AlpineJs) at the click of the new tab.

Like this:

```
<span :class="{ 'text-price': tab === 'top-seller' }" @click="tab = 'top-seller', $dispatch('reloadActiveCarousel')" class="cursor-pointer tab-title mx-8 mx-4 font-medium">Top seller</span>
       <span :class="{ 'text-price': tab === 'audio' }" @click="tab = 'audio', $dispatch('reloadActiveCarousel')" class="cursor-pointer tab-title mx-4 font-medium">Audio</span>
       <span :class="{ 'text-price': tab === 'luci' }" @click="tab = 'luci', $dispatch('reloadActiveCarousel')" class="cursor-pointer tab-title mx-4 font-medium">Luci</span>
       <span :class="{ 'text-price': tab === 'effetti' }" @click="tab = 'effetti', $dispatch('reloadActiveCarousel')" class="cursor-pointer tab-title mx-4 font-medium">Effetti</span>
       <span :class="{ 'text-price': tab === 'video' }" @click="tab = 'video', $dispatch('reloadActiveCarousel')" class="cursor-pointer tab-title mx-4 font-medium">Video</span>
```

So at each tab change I'm trying to reload the carousel, and this is the event:

```
 window.addEventListener('reloadActiveCarousel', () => {
            console.log("active tab");
            const carouselElements = document.querySelectorAll(
                `[data-content-type="products"][data-appearance="carousel"],
                [data-content-type="slider"]`
            );

            if (carouselElements.length > 0) {
                const script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';

                carouselElements.addEventListener('onload', () => {
                    initCarousels(carouselElements);
                });

                script.src = '<?= $escaper->escapeJs($escaper->escapeUrl($gliderUrl)) ?>';
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            }
        });
```

When I click on a new tab I can see the `console.log(active tab)` on the console. But the situation is still the same. Only the first one is working.

How can I fix this problem guys?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say you have to loop across carouselElements.

Comment: I'm trying now, I'll let you know, thanks :)

Comment: It didn't work, I looped over carouselElements and add the event on each element, but it's not working.

Comment: I guess you checked but carouselElements is not empty right? I mean, it's going through the logic inside the if statement, right?

Comment: You mean like `if(carouselElement.length > 0)` and then add the event right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: it didn't work either